# Best practices to process 500k+ requests

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, api, dataset, flask-restplus

I finished my first Python RESTful API (with [Flask RESTPlus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus)) few days ago, and I wrote a small program to test it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
with open('dataset.csv') as dataset:
    reader = csv.DictReader(dataset)
    nb_requests = 0
    for row in reader:
        data = json.dumps(row)
        nb_requests += 1
        requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=header)
```

The problem is the following :

I have a quite huge CSV dataset that I need to test (500k+ lines) and I need to make a POST request to my API for each line inside it.

As expected it's slow because both program are synchronous and I was wondering what would be the best practices to make it faster ?

I read about multithreading, multiprocessing, asyncio ... But I actually don't know what would be the best solution in order to make the API and my testing program faster. Any suggestions ?

Thanks for your lights!

Comment: You will definitely get a speedup of your testing application by parallelizing the `requests.post` call, however it may complicate your script. Usually in this type of scenario, you would want to create a pool of threads/processes for issuing the network request. I would recommend looking into the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: You mention "I need to make a POST request to my API for each line inside it.", does that mean you are going to make 500 000 POST to your API? In that case, I would first suggest to POST the full CSV to your API (reduce network latency), and then proceed as @Ross says and implement a thread pool.

Comment: As @asettouf mentioned, the best solution would be to allow your API to accept the full CSV in one network call. The network requests will most likely be the slowest part of your stack, so limiting the number of network calls will provide the best performance overall.

Comment: @asettouf I need to do a line per line validation (the API does operations on each line it receives and compare it to an existing output in order to validate the data) and unfortunatly sending line per line is in the specs and I need to be compliant with them so sending the hole CSV isn't possible here..

Comment: @Ross In fact the networking stuff "only" takes 30% of the all processing so yeah it still would be 30% less but I can't do that at the moment.. I'm going to implement a thread pool following your advice !

Comment: 30% is a huge gain, nothing says you might gain as much with multi threading (you can check for instance Amdahl's law), especially when those 30% are gained almost for free. All you'd need to do is modify slightly your API to check each line (with a function for instance), and then you can as well reuse that function if you feel like implementing a Thread pool. I'd really argue with the writer of the specs and highlight the loss of time (30%!) by POSTing each line instead of the full CSV